# Can single google API key be used for streetview, geocoding and google maps services?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, api-key

I want to use streetview, geocoding and googlemaps services. 
Can i use single API key for these?

Is it right thing to use single API keys for all google services?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use 1 API key but you will have to enable API for every google service you want to use in your app.
https://console.developers.google.com/

Go to Google Developers console and create a Project and get a KEY.
After then, click on Library and enable the API for every service you want to use.